# Binary Search balanced Trees Successor amortized run time

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree, amortized-analysis

I need to make a case for the amortized run time for the successor function in a balanced bst. 
I know that if starting from the lowest leaf,and going to the "greatest" node is the sequence then the average run time is O(1), because of the T(n)/n => O(n)/n => O(1)

but I am not certain what happens when the sequence is not the longest one.
I would gladly receive help in that regard.

Comment: Are we assuming here that the nodes have parent pointers?

Comment: yeap we are assuming that